# How to group by phrases in multi-dimensional python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter

I'm trying to match exact phrases in a list to tweets. If a tweet has any of the items in the list phrase, I want to add that to my result which can tell me if the tweet is to my interest.

Then I want to sum up the found phrases by grouping them across the tweets and use Twitter's favourite, retweet count to have my result set which tells me if my phrases are popular.

So far I have got to a point where I can match tweets text to my phrases list. But the problem I see is, that this is becoming O(n2) in complexity & I'm not a python purist. But can someone give me an idea how to approach the solution?

I know the code is incomplete, but I'm not finding a way to approach this problem.

```
attributes = ["denim", "solid", "v-neck"]

tweets = ["#hashtag1 new maternity autumn denim A -line dresses solid knee-length v-neck",
          "RT @amyohconnor: Thank you, Daily Mail, for addressing working women's chief concern: how to dress for dosy male colleagues who don't appre…",
          "Why are so many stores selling little girl dresses for women? Its so fucking creepy",
          "top Online Shopping Indian Dresses for Women Salwar Kameez Suits Design Indian Dresses in amazon"
          ]

i = 0
trending_attributes = []
for tweet in tweets:
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    found_attributes = []
    for attribute in attributes:
        if attribute.lower() in tweet:
            found_attributes.append(attribute)
    trending_attributes.append([i, found_attributes])
    i += 1

print(trending_attributes)
```

Output as of now,

```
[[0, ['denim', 'knee-length', 'solid', 'v-neck']], [1, []], [2, ['girl', 'ny']], [3, ['pin', 'shopping']]]
```

What I'm looking for:

```
attrib1: RetweetCount, FavouriteCount
attrib2: RetweetCount, FavouriteCount
attrib3: RetweetCount, FavouriteCount
```

Comment: are your phrases all one word long (no intermediate spaces)

Comment: no, it can multiple words & I'm not trying fuzzy match yet

Comment: I'm not familiar with twitter so pls explain what exactly 'retweetcout ' and 'favouritecount' mean. I gues`RetweetCount` means: attribute found in n-tweets, right? what about `FavouriteCount`?

Comment: twitter may have an api for searches like this, designed to be far more efficient than we mere mortals

Answer (score 0):

If your attributes don’t have spaces inside of them (or don’t overlap), you can get this down to `O(n)` complexity (average case, per tweet) using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set).

```
tweet = "we begin our story in new york"
words = set(tweet.split())
for attribute in attributes:
    if attribute in words:
        found_attributes.append(attribute)
```

If your phrases are multiple words long, and you want to be clever, consider creating a dictionary with the words as keys and sets of the positions as values

```
positions = {"we": {0}, "our": {2}, "begin": {1} ... }
```

Then loop through the words in each attribute, and see if they are in sequential order. This should be `O(1)` for each lookup making it `O(n)` for the *total* number of words in your attributes. Creating the `positions` dictionary is `O(m)` (where `m` is the number of words in the tweet) since you iterate through `enumerated(tweet.split())` to make it. Keep in mind you still have to do this for *every* tweet in your list.

Tweets are more or less of constant size size, though, so asymptotic analysis is not very useful here. If you are looking for relationships between two arrays of data, it will usually be at a minimum `O(p*q)` where `p` and `q` are the dimensions of the data. I don’t think you can do much better than quadratic time if both your attributes and your list of tweets are of variable size. However I suspect your attributes list is of “constant” size, so this may effectively be linear in time.